# Laravel not showing image from url

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I have issue with access some of images from my Storage on shared hosting.

For example: `<my_domain>/storage/captcha/baa5271fe19d696d6e83388a5c22f13c40ecc470.jpg` display html page but `<my_domain>/storage/images/slider1.jpg` display image.

`Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` is used to generate captcha image.

filesystems.php config to compare:

```php
        'captcha' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/captcha'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/captcha/',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>  storage_path('app/public/images'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/images/',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Privileges for Storage was set as 777. **storage:link** was also set.

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It's happening **only on shared hosting** so I guess it's something with .htaccess.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was delete storage directory from public and execute storage:link command again.

Answer (score -1):

as you are using **shared hosting** use `public` path insted of `storage` path

```php
    'captcha' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path() . '/captcha',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/captcha',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path() . '/images',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and only gives **folder name**
it's working for me you can try it.

Comment: It's not valid solution. root path is good with storage_path.

Comment: storage:link create symlink of laravel storage path which is not possible in some shared hosting provider if you are able to do that then try diffrent solution

Answer (score -2):

If you are using shared hosting then use public path

```
'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>  public_path() . '/Any folder name of image',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/images/',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```